# How do I create any Collection given the collection name(ArrayList, LinkedList etc) and items in the collection?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I am trying to create a method that accepts the type of collection and the type of items inside the collection.

`ArrayList<Integer> ints = getCollection(ArrayList.class, Integer.class);`

How do I write the ***getCollection*** so that, given any Collection subclass and any Number subclass, the method should create a collection and populate it with random elements of Number or subtype of Number?

Comment: If you have to say `ArrayList` anyway, wouldn't it be easier just to use `new ArrayList<>()`?

Comment: `if (listClass == ArrayList.class) { ... }` You probably won't get any solution better than casework, at least for each element independently.  Also, generifying over different types of `Number` is 99% of the time not worth it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, it would be better to pass in a Supplier for the collection, and a Function to convert from Number to the sub-type, such as:

```java
    private static final SecureRandom RND = new SecureRandom();
    private static final int COUNT_MAX = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> ints = getCollection(ArrayList::new, Number::intValue);
        System.out.println(ints);
        Set<Double> doubles = getCollection(HashSet::new, Number::doubleValue);
        System.out.println(doubles);
    }

    private static <T extends Collection<U>, U extends Number> T getCollection(
        Supplier<T> supplier, Function<Number, U> fn) {
        T collection = supplier.get();
        int count = RND.nextInt(COUNT_MAX);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            collection.add(fn.apply(RND.nextInt()));
        return collection;
    }
```

This way, you won't need any casting.

**Update** using streams:

```java
    private static <T extends Collection<U>, U extends Number> T getCollection(
        Supplier<T> supplier, Function<Number, U> fn) {
        int count = RND.nextInt(COUNT_MAX);
        return RND.ints().limit(count).boxed().map(fn)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(supplier));
    }
```

Comment: Wonderful answer. Can we solve this question with Collectors?

Comment: Ah yes that would be neater, will add to above answer

Comment: Beautiful solution.